# Interfacing external C code with duplicate method names using Cython

Tags: python, c, gcc, cython

I want to provide a native interface to some C code from my Python code. For this I decided on *Cython*.

In this specific case, I have some C files which have duplicate names, resulting in compilation issues. Is there any way I can circumvent this? The solution from the official documentation (https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/external_C_code.html#resolving-naming-conflicts-c-name-specifications) does not seem to be sufficient.

The following example has been stripped down to demonstrate the issue, while my actual use case is for a larger third-party library. In the best case, I can avoid having multiple `*.so` files with similar content. I might need to use the different definitions of the same method during runtime.

---

##### Example

```py
# File setup.py
from setuptools import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(
    ext_modules = cythonize("my_test.pyx", language_level=3)
)
```

```py
# File my_test.pyx
from binding cimport add as _add, subtract as _subtract, module1_main as _main

print('Hello World')


def add(a, b):
    return _add(a, b)


def subtract(a, b):
    return _subtract(a, b)


def main():
    return _main()
```

```py
# File binding.pxd
cdef extern from "module1.c":
    int add (int a, int b)
    int subtract (int a, int b)
    int module1_main "main" ()


cdef extern from "module2.c":
    int module2_main "main" ()
```

```c
// File module1.c
#include <stdio.h>

static int add(int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
}


static int subtract(int a, int b) {
    return a - b;
}


int main() {
    printf("Result: %d", add(40, 2));
    return 0;
}
```

```c
// File module2.c
#include <stdio.h>


int main() {
    printf("Hello from module 2");
    return 0;
}
```

##### Error message

```
(venv) user@host ~/path/to/directory $ python setup.py build_ext --inplace
Compiling my_test.pyx because it changed.
[1/1] Cythonizing my_test.pyx
running build_ext
building 'my_test' extension
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -fPIC -I. "-I/home/user/path/to/directory/venv/include" -I/usr/include/python3.8 -c my_test.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/my_test.o
In file included from my_test.c:716:
module2.c:4:5: error: redefinition of ‘main’
    4 | int main() {
      |     ^~~~
In file included from my_test.c:715:
module1.c:13:5: note: previous definition of ‘main’ was here
   13 | int main() {
      |     ^~~~
error: command '/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Generally `static` is used to restrict functions to a single complication unit, and so you need to modify your C files and make the duplicate functions `static`. Defining the functions as `static` would allow you to create *separate* Cython modules wrapping the function, but not allow you to use the conflicting functions in the same modules like you're trying to do here. The flip-side of doing this is you must include the function definitions in your Cython file - you can't just include a header and link it later.
- `main` has a special meaning in C (it defines a starting point for a full program), so you almost certainly don't want C functions called `main`.
- The Cython "cname" feature you link `int module2_main "main" ()` doesn't (and will never!) solve your problem. It essentially lets you refer to `main` as `module2_main` in your Cython code only. It still gets translated to C code `main`, and so your conflicting definitions are still a problem.
- This is an issue that you have to solve in C (probably by renaming the functions). If the C libraries are truly external and you can't modify them then you're pretty much stuck.

---

Quick addendum with a little bit of testing:

- You can wrap a function called `main()` with Cython;
- If you want to wrap two different functions called with the same name then they must go in different Cython modules.
- Because of the way that Cython imports modules dynamically, there's no conflict between the two modules at run-time.

But this is mostly a C/linker problem...

Comment: My goal with this is to natively call some tools which I would otherwise use subprocesses for, so providing access to `main` would be the easiest approach here in my opinion. Nevertheless, even without exposing `main` in the `binding.pxd` file, the error will be the same.

Comment: Thank you for the explanations. The external library is open source, so I should be able to patch the conflicting lines to fix compilation. In fact I already suspected that this actually is a C problem which has no easy solution, but I wanted to make sure that I did not miss any feature which Cython might provide.

Comment: @epR8GaYuh testing it on my PC suggest: 1) you can wrap a function called `main` in Cython without problems, 2) if you want to wrap 2 functions called `main` you'll have to create multiple Cython modules. So I think it should be possible to do what you want